# Wallpaper not properly fit on device screen when using "InputStream"

Tags: java, android

I have sets of images in different folders online. I have one button to set images as wallpaper on device screen. Once button is pressed, Wallpapers start changing automatically (one image per day as a new wallpaper on your device). Problem: wallpapers are not fit properly on some of the devices that I tested.

This is the code:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;


public class WallpaperService extends IntentService {

    public static final String STANDARD = "standard";

    public WallpaperService() {
        super("martynas_notification_service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        changeRandomly(this);
    }


    public void changeRandomly(Context context) {

        Set<String> urls = getSavedUrls();

        if (urls == null) {
            return;
        }

        String randomUrl = getRandomUrl(urls);

        WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        try {

            InputStream ins = new URL(randomUrl).openStream();
            wpm.setStream(ins);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

    private Set<String> getSavedUrls() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(STANDARD, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getStringSet(ExitAppActivity.CHOSEN_FOLDER_URLS, null);
    }

    private String getRandomUrl(Set<String> urls) {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(urls.size());
        return (String) urls.toArray()[randomNumber];
    }
}
```

Some people suggest using DisplayMetrics, BitmapFactory, but I am not sure how to use it with InputStream + Randomly changing wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. It works.

...

```
public void changeRandomly(Context context) {


        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;


    Set<String> urls = getSavedUrls();

    if (urls == null) {
        return;
    }

    String randomUrl = getRandomUrl(urls);

    try {

        InputStream ins = new URL(randomUrl).openStream();

        Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap, width, height, true);

        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
        wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

...